# Default value in filter in django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I have a view like this:

```
if request.GET.has_key('ic_iteration') and request.GET['ic_iteration'] != 'all':
    # Filter with ic_iteration
    iteration = request.GET['ic_iteration']
    context['iteration'] = request.GET['ic_iteration']
    persons = Person.objects.filter(organisation__name="The Interaction Consortium").filter(assemblaticket__ic_iteration=iteration).annotate(estimate_total=Sum('assemblaticket__estimate'))
    context['persons'] = persons
    context['iciteration'] = ICIteration.objects.all()
    return render_to_response("willard/persons_ic.html", context)     
else:
    # Default
    iteration = ICIteration.objects.get_current()
    context['iteration'] = iteration
    # get all persons related to the interation consortium with total of all estimates for all tickets
    persons = Person.objects.filter(organisation__name="The Interaction Consortium").filter(assemblaticket__ic_iteration=iteration).annotate(estimate_total=Sum('assemblaticket__estimate'))
    context['persons'] = persons
    context['iciteration'] = ICIteration.objects.all()
    return render_to_response("willard/persons_ic.html", context)
```

In the template:

```
IC Iteration: <select name="ic_iteration">
<option value="all">--All--</option>
  {% for ic_iteration in iciteration %}
  <option value="{{ ic_iteration.id }}" {% if iteration == ic_iteration.id|stringformat:"s" %}selected="selected"{% endif %}>{{ ic_iteration.name }}</option>
  {% endfor %}
</select>
```

When I first access the page, it goes to the else statement and pass the **iteration** context. But no matter what the select option shows at `-All-`, but if I later change the filter and hit apply `{% if iteration == ic_iteration.id|stringformat:"s" %}selected="selected"{% endif %}` works. What's wrong?

Comment: This should be solved using a form.

Comment: `iteration = forms.ChoiceField(ICIteration.objects.all)' throws not iterable error.